# WooCommerce Checkout Fields are not showing the correct error message

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I get vague error messages in my WooCommerce checkout because I have removed all labels. Is there a way to display the correct error message while hiding labels with PHP? Or is there a way to hide the checkout labels with CSS, but without having to hide all labels, seeing as some of them are relevant (Terms and conditions, Newsletter etc).

We use the following code to hide labels:

```
// Fjern labels fra checkout
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
// Action: remove label from $fields
function custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label($fields) {
    // loop by category
    foreach ($fields as $category => $value) {
        // loop by fields
        foreach ($fields[$category] as $field => $property) {
            // remove label property
            unset($fields[$category][$field]['label']);
        }
    }
     return $fields;
}
```

**Alternatively CSS can work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you could try using a specific CSS rule to hide the billing `<label>` tags using:

```css
.woocommerce-billing-fields label{
    display:none;
}
```

*This goes on styles.css file of your active child theme (or active theme)…*

It should work. This way you will get the correct error messages.

Comment: Thank you! I was targeting the wrong tags, so I ended up hiding more labels than I intended. I also removed the unsetting PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

[Update 1] -- added some more information on how errors are generated.

[Update 2] -- explained how to get specific language locale activated for WooCommerce

[Update 3] -- added CSS rules as original question was modified.

---

The errors are generated inside `validate_posted_data` function of `class-wc-checkout.php`.

The `Field names` that you see in errors such as *First Name* in *"Billing First Name is a required field."* are in fact `labels`. So if your checkout fields' array don't have `['label']`property set for any of the fields than you won't get correct complete errors.

In current scenario, I assume you have removed the `['label']` properties to hide labels on front-end and only show `['placeholders']`. If you want to hide Labels in front-end use CSS styles for that.

```
/*
 * CSS Styles are from .visuallyhidden rule of
 * HTML5Boilerplate for proper accessibility. 
 * 
 * @Link: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/6.0.1/dist/doc/css.md#visuallyhidden
 */
.woocommerce-shipping-fields__field-wrapper label,
.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper label {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* 1 */
}
```

This rule will only and only target Billing & Shipping Field labels.

I am using code from [`.visuallyhidden`](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/76f6b7d95358ffabb6ac6c4bc8d44a5af35fea8d/dist/css/main.css#L137) [utility class](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/6.0.1/dist/doc/css.md#visuallyhidden) of HTML5Boilerplate. This is the most accessible way to hide content visually but not for screen readers or other assisting technologies.

---

## Why your approach is wrong?

Best way to [localize WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/) is not by filtering output and replacing the English text to your language. Danish seems to be near 100% done both for [Wordpress](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/4.8.x/da/default) and [WooCommerce](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/da/default/wp-plugins/woocommerce)

If you have selected the install language as Danish, you should not be required to add Danish placeholders as you are doing right now.

**Follow steps in this link to have Danish localization for WooCommerce: [https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-4](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-4__)**

Comment: @eMikkelsen I have updated the answer with more details and have improved wordings for better understanding.

Comment: I see. However with CSS it removes all labels, also labels such as terms and conditions and our newsletter in the checkout. Is there really no way to tell the php to read from the placeholder or to make error messages with php?

Comment: Updated the answer with better CSS code so accessibility is maintained even when elements are hidden.

Comment: @DhavalShah I have not updated original question and author either. I have just add a tag to it… Now as I have suggested CSS in my answer, you have changed your answer from pure PHP to CSS… Kindly but this is not the right way to do things on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Original question was changed once I pointed out that `label` property is used while displaying errors and which seemed to be missing. First I gave PHP code based on code from original question, then I pointed out CSS solution should be used on which author changed the question. Kindly check edit history both for question and my answer. TBH I thought such a senior member like you would do a check before accusing another member of playing games.